# Selecting a single row from a joined table per row of main table

Tags: mysql

I've tried working through some previous answers, but they aren't making a lot of sense.

I have two tables, one of "groups" representing real-world groups of people, and one of "events" representing meetings of the group.

I've got a terribly simple query that selects the groups, to show them in a list on the website, and a separate query on the group profile page that lists their upcoming meetings, and I'm unsure what technique to use to add the "next meeting" to the list of groups, ideally it needs to be returned as another column in the MySQL query.

I've been fine with joins before, but limiting the number of joined results to one, per row in the first table, doesn't seem to straightforward.

Any simple advice on what technique would work to show this?

Thanks!

Rough schema as follows;

```
CREATE TABLE `groups` (
  `id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`slug`)
)

CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `finish` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: to get a working answer you need to show the table structure and the queries you already got!

Comment: It would be easier if you posted some schema definitions.

Comment: I asked for a technique, not someone to do it for me, but I'll add one now

Comment: Are you familiar with `GROUP BY` clauses? Because you'll need one, and it *sounds* like that's what you're missing.

Comment: @MatthewHiggins: it's not that we are eager to write the code for you. Having some concrete names helps some people think. Also, there may be nuances in the code you forgot to tell about. We're all programmers here, we read code better than plain text :-)

Comment: @ruakh: he's gonna need a little bit more than that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema you present is NOT consistent AND you did not provide your queries...

To give some sort of answer I made the assumption that `groups.id = events.group`.

To show the next event you could do something similar to this:

```
SELECT G.*, M.EVENT FROM GROUPS G LEFT JOIN 
(
SELECT X.GROUP, MIN ( X.ID ) EVENT 
FROM EVENTS X 
INNER JOIN (SELECT E.GROUP G, MIN ( E.START ) S FROM EVENTS E WHERE E.START > NOW() GROUP BY E.GROUP) Y 
ON X.GROUP = Y.G AND X.START = Y.S
GROUP BY X.GROUP
) M ON G.ID = M.GROUP
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is answer with technique, not solution :-)

This code selects every two rows from child table for each parent row, sorted by `sort` column.

```
SELECT
    parent.id, parent.name,
    c1.id, c1.name
FROM parent
JOIN child c1 ON c1.parent_id = parent.id
LEFT JOIN child c2 ON c2.parent_id = c1.parent_id AND c2.sort < c1.sort
GROUP BY parent.id, parent.name, c1.id, c1.name
HAVING COUNT(c2.id) < 2
ORDER BY parent.name;
```

Taken [from here](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?20,135077,135103#msg-135103).